# Transform every 3 columns into multiple rows in Excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

My data looks like this.

[image: Data in excel sheet 1]

I need to transform the data like below into a new sheet - sheet2 (say). Total no of rows (ID) is 2300. I want to loop the code so that it will transform all the rows.

I am new to coding. I tried the following code in vba in excel but unable to produce the required result.

[image: Output should be like this in sheet 2 or new sheet]

Code i tried: i searched for loop code and applied here.

```
Sub Sheet1_Arrangement()

'UpdatebyExtendoffice20161222
      Dim x As Integer
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      ' Set numrows = number of rows of Sheet1.
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      ' Select cell a1.
      Range("A2").Select
      ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
      For x = 1 To NumRows
         ' Insert your code here.
         Range("E2,F2,G2").Select
    Range("G2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("H2:J2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("K2:M2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("N2:P2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("Q2:S2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("T2:V2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("W2:Y2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("Z2:AB2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B10").Select
         ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      
'
' Sheet1_Arrangement Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
    
End Sub
```

This code looks messy as i tried with my little knowledge of recording macros in excel. Please help me in getting the output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Rename as appropriate
sourceSheet = "sheet1"
destSheet = "sheet2


'These are starting point for destination sheet population
iRows2 = 1
iCols2 = 1

iRows1 = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(sheets(sourceSheet).cells(iRows1,1))
    iCols1 = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(sheets(sourceSheet).cells(iRows1,iCols1))
        Range(sheets(sourceSheet).cells(iRows1,iCols1), sheets(sourceSheet).cells(iRows1,iCols1+2)).Copy

        sheets(destSheet).cells(iRows2,iCols2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        iRows2 = iRows2 + 1

        iCols1 = iCols1 + 3
    Loop
    iRows1 = iRows1 + 1
Loop
```

I think thats you sorted...?

Basically, iterating over your columns on the inner loop rather than rows makes it easier to sort.

You may want to disable screen updating and calculations to make it quicker, do this by:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

at the start of your script, then reenable at the end via:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic   
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

(screen updating back to true after calculation is a bit quicker)

edit: Sorry, needed to space the "Do Until"

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply. When i ran the above code it gave compile error. Sub or Function not defined.

Comment: My bad, "DoUntil" should be "Do Until"

Comment: Yeah i corrected in the code and ran. See the code in pic.  https://imgur.com/a/H1Jtjie

Comment: Don't dim the sourceSheet and destSheet as worksheets, I have them as strings (which is probably bad practice on my part!)